# Totally bounded subset

Tags: metric-spaces

We have a metric space $\boldsymbol{(X,d)}$ and $\boldsymbol Y$ is included in $\boldsymbol{X}$, a subset.

How can we prove that $\boldsymbol Y$ is totally bounded if and only if the **closure of Y** is totally bounded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing an assumption? (e.g., $X$ is totally bounded)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Math.StackExchange. Why is this question interesting for you? What did you tried? These question are simply examples of providing context for your question: this will help other members help you.

Comment: I corrected the question ! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The implication "$Y$ totally bounded then $\overline{Y}$ is totally bounded", is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2789992/4280) among other places. (it's one of the "related" links on the right part of the web page; always good to pay attention to those..)

A subset of a totally bounded set is still totally bounded and this takes care of the other direction.